# Best way to split an unsigned 64-bit integer to its bytes

Tags: integer, bit-manipulation, nim-lang

I have an `uint64` (what would be an `unsigned long long` in C) which I want to convert in an array of bytes.

**This is how I'm doing it right now (in Nim code):**

- `Value` is *typedef*'d as `unsigned long long`
- `Byte` is *typedef*'d as `unsigned char`
- `CD` is an array of `Byte`s

```c
        proc writeValue(v:Value) =
            CD.add(Byte(v shr 56))
            CD.add(Byte(v and Value(0x00ff000000000000)))
            CD.add(Byte(v and Value(0x0000ff0000000000)))
            CD.add(Byte(v and Value(0x000000ff00000000)))
            CD.add(Byte(v and Value(0x00000000ff000000)))
            CD.add(Byte(v and Value(0x0000000000ff0000)))
            CD.add(Byte(v and Value(0x000000000000ff00)))
            CD.add(Byte(v and Value(0x00000000000000ff)))
```

**And this is how I'm reading it back** (get an `uint64` starting from a specific position in the array: `IP`)

```c
template readValue():Value =
    inc(IP,8); (Value(CD[IP-8]) shl 56) or (Value(CD[IP-7]) shl 48) or (Value(CD[IP-6]) shl 40) or (Value(CD[IP-5]) shl 32) or (Value(CD[IP-4]) shl 24) or (Value(CD[IP-3]) shl 16) or (Value(CD[IP-2]) shl 8) or Value(CD[IP-1])
```

---

Is there a more efficient way? Am I wasting performance the way I'm doing it?

Comment: This is not [tag:c]..

Comment: In C it's easy, since it allows type-punning using unions.

Comment: @LPs Well, the code above is not C - it's Nim. But, first Nim and C are pretty much intertwined (Nim produces C code), and second, what I need is not a language-specific solution.

Comment: Anyways, given that I got my "C" tag removed and that most of you probably do not know how Nim works... I can use pure C code as well. It really doesn't matter. In Nim, the two can be mixed. I just need to see if there's any fault in my logic...

Comment: You are asking for performances and this is closely related to the implementation language. Even more so in case of a language that produce, as output, another langue source code (double indirection).

Comment: For example, using [tag:c], you can use `union` to directly access bytes...

Answer (score 1):

There is an more efficient way. I am not sure if it is safe and it does not depend on a particular machine and/or architecture.

Anyway. You can do it using `cast`:
https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#statements-and-expressions-type-casts

```
type Value = uint64
type Byte = uint8
type ValueBytes = array[0..7, Byte]

proc toBytes(v: Value): ValueBytes =
  result = cast[ValueBytes](v)

proc toValue(bytes: ValueBytes): Value =
  result = cast[Value](bytes)

proc toBytesManual(v: Value): ValueBytes =
  result[0] = Byte((v shr 0) and Value(0xff))
  result[1] = Byte((v shr 8) and Value(0xff))
  result[2] = Byte((v shr 16) and Value(0xff))
  result[3] = Byte((v shr 24) and Value(0xff))
  result[4] = Byte((v shr 32) and Value(0xff))
  result[5] = Byte((v shr 40) and Value(0xff))
  result[6] = Byte((v shr 48) and Value(0xff))
  result[7] = Byte((v shr 56) and Value(0xff))

proc toValueManual(bytes: ValueBytes): Value =
  result += Value(bytes[0]) shl 0
  result += Value(bytes[1]) shl 8
  result += Value(bytes[2]) shl 16
  result += Value(bytes[3]) shl 24
  result += Value(bytes[4]) shl 32
  result += Value(bytes[5]) shl 40
  result += Value(bytes[6]) shl 48
  result += Value(bytes[7]) shl 56

let value = 123456789'u64
let bytes = [21'u8, 205'u8, 91'u8, 7'u8, 0'u8, 0'u8, 0'u8, 0'u8]

assert toBytes(value) == bytes
assert toBytesManual(value) == toBytes(value)
assert toValue(bytes) == value
assert toValue(bytes) == toValueManual(bytes)
```